# Flipper and ListView in android

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using Flipper as parent and Listview as child. My problem here is the flipping and clicking of item in listview. When I flip to next page (by dragging from right to left) I accidentally click a list Item.

**How will I disable the onClick of listview when I already made a gesture for flipping?**

Code:

Flipper Ontouch:

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(touchevent);
        switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        lastX = touchevent.getX();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        float currentX = touchevent.getX();
        if (lastX - 100 > currentX) {
            if (result_pageNum < max_pageNum) {
                result_pageNum++;
                if (vf.getDisplayedChild() == 0) {
                    listView[1].setClickable(false);
                    setListView(1);
                } else {
                    listView[0].setClickable(false);
                    setListView(0);
                }
                vf.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_right);
                vf.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);
                vf.showNext();
            }
        } else if (lastX + 100 < currentX) {
            if (result_pageNum > 0) {
                result_pageNum--;
                if (vf.getDisplayedChild() == 1) {
                    listView[0].setClickable(false);
                    setListView(0);
                } else {
                    listView[1].setClickable(false);
                    setListView(1);
                }
                vf.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);
                vf.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);
                vf.showPrevious();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

listView onClick:

```
private void listView_onClick() {
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.length; i++) {
        listView[i].setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

Toast.maketext(this,"Working!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't believe ViewFlipper was developed with complex ViewGroups (such as ListView) in mind. I've only used before for simple ImageView. Said that, I've used ViewPager with list views, map fragments, and it works fine. Maybe you should reconsider and change to it.

Answer (score 0):

In your dispatchTouchEvent method, when a fling gesture has been detected (under ACTION_UP event), try returning ***true*** as a boolean value rather that returning false every time. When no fling gesture is detected according to your movement calculation, then only return ***false*** .

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be using `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` for this purpose.

Instead you should use `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` and `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`.

The relationship between these methods are documented in the methods' Javadoc, but as a summary:

`onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` decides whether a `ViewGroup` intercepts a user touch events from any of it's child views. For instance, your `ViewFlipper` decides whether the ListView recieves the events.

`onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` is where your `ViewFlipper` can actually react to it's touch events.

Comment: Thank you for the time. I am searching for samples for onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent) but I can not find some. I am confused how to use it. My `Flipper` will be on `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`? but what will I put in `onInterceptTouchevent(MotionEvent)`?

Comment: Why not use [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) instead of ViewFlipper? It already has all of this implemented for you.

Comment: Is it possible like ViewFlipper? without having another xml to change to? only Child Views. I have not tried that but I tried ViewPager from xml to another xml.

Comment: ViewPager is an AdapterView, so you need to provide an Adapter to populate it with Views (similar to ListView, etc).